# Map source for iLife '11?

Tags: data, apple

The new iLife has map functionality, what's the source of the map data used?

[image: ilife map image]

Further pictures [on engadget](http://www.engadget.com/2010/10/20/live-from-apples-back-to-the-mac-event/), which show a city-level view.

Comment: Probably what apple has been rumored to be developing in house...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are Google Maps images underneath. If you open [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&ll=-37.579413,110.390625&spn=75.197901,158.027344&z=3), you can see that the label placement for the Indian Ocean and Tasman Sea match the maps shown. At the more zoomed in maps on the Engadget page, it looks like they're using the "Terrain" tileset, but they are also Google. In fact, you can even see the "Google" logo in the lower left corner and the classic Google copyright in the lower right. (Granted, you usually don't see Google on a screen of a resolution of this high.)

It does look like they're in a custom app, but that's not new for Apple, which has been using Google Maps on the iPhone Maps app for some time.

Answer (score 3):

Google Map Data, Europa Technologies MapData Sciences Plty. LTD, PSMA MapLind., TeleAtlas, Geocentre Consulting at the world scale.

No data attribution on the photo album page.

The source for this is: http://www.apple.com/ilife/iphoto/#laptop-gallery03